# lua: `zlib` not compatible with HTTP?

Tags: lua, gzip

I'm using `wrk` to test my HTTP server, so Lua is the preferred script to construct HTTP body.

When using lua's `zlib` package:

```
zlib = require 'zlib'
md5 = require 'md5'
x = zlib.deflate(5,31)("abcdefghigklmn", "finish")
print(md5.sumhexa(x))
```

I got `f2fa3c8e97506f0d6e27248a82b9b76d`, but when using golang's `gzip` (I've used in my client & server, and it's HTTP compatible), I got different value `34b6ba0659ded8aa506e07afc01dd1f8`:

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "crypto/md5"
    "compress/gzip"
    "encoding/hex"
)

var buf bytes.Buffer
g := gzip.NewWriter(&buf)
g.Write([]byte{"abcdefghigklmn"})
h := md5.New()
h.Write(buf.Bytes())
fmt.Printf("%s", hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil)))
```

Is there any other lua's `gzip` implements that compatible with HTTP gzip?

Comment: Yes, `zip` and `gzip` are different formats (compressing method is the same, but archive headers are [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45216069/lua-how-to-gzip-a-string-gzip-not-zlib-in-memory)).

Comment: I play with pegasus server and it uses lua-zlib/lzlib libraries to compress gzip. https://github.com/moteus/pegasus.lua/blob/master/src/pegasus/compress.lua